# Bootstrap framework not included in the angular-cli

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, angular, npm, angular-cli

I have installed the bootstrap framework to the angular2 project via npm and it shows in the node-modules folder.But, the angular-cli file does not have the boostrap script as well as css.

```
"apps": [
    {
      "root": "src",
      "outDir": "dist",
      "assets": [
        "assets",
        "favicon.ico"
      ],
      "index": "index.html",
      "main": "main.ts",
      "polyfills": "polyfills.ts",
      "test": "test.ts",
      "tsconfig": "tsconfig.app.json",
      "testTsconfig": "tsconfig.spec.json",
      "prefix": "app",
      "styles": [
        "styles.css"
      ],
      "scripts": [],
      "environmentSource": "environments/environment.ts",
      "environments": {
        "dev": "environments/environment.ts",
        "prod": "environments/environment.prod.ts"
      }
    }
  ],
```

I manually tried to add the bootstrap location css,js file in the angular-cli file and restarted,but it shows build errors.Is there any other solution to resolve this issue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are instructions in the Angular CLI documentation here: https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/wiki/stories-include-bootstrap

Comment: @DeborahK, I just want to say I really enjoyed your angular-cli tutorial. I found it really helpful :)

Comment: Thank you so much. It's great to hear.

Answer (score 1):

You need to add the css file in `styles` array like below:

```
"styles": ["styles.css", "../node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css"]
```

If you need bootstrap js file, you can add it like follows:

```
"scripts": ["../node_modules/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js"]
```